# Power of power modulo with non square-free numbers

Tags: number-theory

Reference https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/devu-police/problem

I have five numbers a, b, c, d, N and I need to find $(a^b)^{c^d}$ mod N. N is non square-free number so euler totient theorem or CRT won't work here.

I have tried this way but according to test-cases my program gets timed out. I find $a^b$ mod N then I run power modulo with algorithm https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/modular-exponentiation-power-in-modular-arithmetic/ here exponent divided by 2 and I do with c so each computation needs O(d) which should not be rather logarithm solution expected.

Could you please help me to solve?

Comment: Euler's totient theorem does not need a squarefree modulo, it is enough that the base is coprime to the modulo.

Comment: This will be useful for your problem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: @Peter if they r not co-prime then what?

Comment: If you know the factorization of $N$, my link should solve the problem.

Comment: @Peter thank you ... :) actually I didn't go through your link .. ;)

Comment: @Peter I have tried with above Carmichael function approach. I found lamda(N) but what if $a^b$ mod N and N is not co-prime?

Comment: Did you read the part "Exponential cycle length" ? You need the following steps : reduce the base modulo $N$ , reduce the exponent modulo $\lambda(N)$. If the exponent gets smaller than the largest exponent in the prime factorization of $N$, just add $\lambda(N)$ to the exponent. This way you get a "handy" power that has the same remainder modulo $N$ than the given power.

Comment: @Peter now it's done, but i need to go through the proof ... otherwise it wud be difficult to figure out such problems later on ... :(